# C# Decode Large/Huge XML / CDATA context in Base64

Tags: c#, stream, base64, out-of-memory, buffer

I got a very large XML **(>1GB)** with `CDATA` content that contans a base64 with 76 characters and CRLF and the last content padded with "=" and no CRLF.

The most natural way to get base64 decode is to use XmlReader reader.ReadElementContentAsBase64(...) but thay stops working at 100Mb. (=OOM)

I found this after searching for a way to stream to Base64 conversion.

```
string Original = "foo bar, this is an example";

byte[] ToBase64; string Decoded;

using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() )  using ( CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( ms, new ToBase64Transform(),
                                                CryptoStreamMode.Write ) )  using ( StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter( cs ) )  {
    st.Write( Original );
    st.Flush();
    ToBase64 = ms.ToArray();  }

using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( ToBase64 ) )  using ( CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( ms, new FromBase64Transform(), 
                                                    CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )  using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( cs ) )      {
    Decoded = sr.ReadToEnd(); }

Console.WriteLine( Original );  Console.WriteLine( Encoding.Default.GetString( ToBase64 ) );  Console.WriteLine( Decoded );
```

This example has a string as input but I need to convert this code to handle a file and start/stop reading from a position within the file.

> ```
>               CData Start                         CDataEnd
>                   |                                 |
>                   V                                 V
> ```
>
> [xml..[Envelope]...[Body]base64 with 76 char + CRLF + padding "="...[/Body]...[/Envelope]

Comment: Just out of the way I am curious to know why you are not using Linq to XML may be it has capability to handle the huge data

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could create..
    int readbytes = 0;

```
                long bytesToRead = (CDataEnd - CDataStart);
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStremFromBase64 = new CryptoStream(context.OutStream, new FromBase64Transform(FromBase64TransformMode.IgnoreWhiteSpaces), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {


                    byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[bytesToRead % 10485760];
                    readbytes = context.InStream.Read(bytebuffer, 0, bytebuffer.Length);
                    cryptoStremFromBase64.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytebuffer.Length);

                    while (context.InStream.Position < CDataEnd)
                    {
                        WriteToLog("Context.Instream.Position = " + context.InStream.Position.ToString(), context, startingTime);
                        byte[] bytebuffer2 = new byte[10485760];
                        readbytes = context.InStream.Read(bytebuffer2, 0, bytebuffer2.Length);
                        cryptoStremFromBase64.Write(bytebuffer2, 0, bytebuffer2.Length);
                    }


                    cryptoStremFromBase64.Flush();

                }
```

Context.InStream is the SOAP with the base64
context.Outstream is the output of the body after converting from base64

Is there any way I can improve this?